# Can't make phone call from Android WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an app with a WebView which loads a list of phone numbers. In some devices, users can't make the call when clicking the phone number.

There are two pages, Page A and Page B. When I load Page A, the user can make the call, but on the same device, if they load Page B, they can't make the call.

I have checked loading both pages from mobile web browsers and web browser from PC. In both cases both A and B work fine. If this is because of something wrong with my WebView setup, user can't make the call from page A, but the user can.

I have no idea what's going on.

> shouldOverrideUrlLoading

```java
  @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
                makePhoneCall(url);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

> makePhoneCall()

```java
    public void makePhoneCall(String phoneNumber) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, REQUEST_CALL);
        checkPermissions();
    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(phoneNumber)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> In some devices, users can't make the call when clicking the phone number

It is because you do not ask runtime permission for `ACTION_CALL` in Android 6 and above

Try using `ACTION_DIAL` instead, `ACTION_CALL` is for making phone call instantly and this is now restricted by Google new SMS and Call policy!

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, uri));
```

Comment: I tried using ACTION_DIAL not working,And this same device is able to make calls from another webpage.

Comment: Would you please wtite the whole function ?